# How many ways are there to distribute $18$ different toys among $4$ children,(a) without restriction?(b) if $2$ children get $7$ toys each and $2$…

Tags: combinatorics

> How many ways are there to distribute $18$ different toys among $4$ children?
> a) without restrictions
> b)  if $2$ children get $7$ toys each and $2$ children get $2$ toys each.

For $1$ since toys are different, then there are $4^{18}$ ways to distribute .

for $2$, Im kind of stuck. I know I have two do it in $2$ cases. Can someone help me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Choose the $2$ children who will get $7$ toys.  Then choose the $7$ toys the older of these will get. Then choose the $7$ for the younger one. Then choose the $2$ toys for the older of the remaining children. That gives a total of $\binom{4}{2}\binom{18}{7}\binom{11}{7}\binom{4}{2}$.

Answer (score 1):

1. $4^18$ works.
2. Choose 2 of them. Then choose 7 toys. There are 7^2 ways to distribute them. Then choose 2 toys and give 1 to 1 child and the other to the other. So we have ${4 \choose 2}{18 \choose 7}7^2{11 \choose 2}2^2$.

I know that Andres' answer assumes that the children each get 7 and they each get 2. Mine assumes that we don't care about the other 9 lost toys. Hope you learn from both examples.

Comment: Please note that it should be if 2 children each  get 7 toys and 2 children each get 2 toys.